# Navigation property null with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I perform an Ajax get request, the server always returns null for the navigation property.

My navigation property is element.Escuderia.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/GestionPilotosEscuderia/GetPiloto",
    }).done(function (data) {
        $(data).each(function (index, element) {
            console.log(element) //here element.Escuderia gives null
        });
    }).error(function (ex) {
        alert("Error");
    });
//Controller
public JsonResult GetPiloto()
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return Json(db.Piloto.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

public partial class Piloto
    {
        public Piloto()
        {
            this.PilotoCarrera = new HashSet<PilotoCarrera>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public int? id_escuderia { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellidos { get; set; }

        public virtual Escuderia Escuderia { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the JSON inside /GestionPilotosEscuderia/GetPiloto

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for Navigation properties you need to include them.

```
return Json(db.Piloto**.Include("Escuderia").**ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

that gives me a circular reference error, if db.piloto.tolist () will go around in the view if I access the navigation property ("Escuderia") but if I get with ajax can not access the property navigation

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved
remove:
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Comment: If i removed this, i started receiving circular reference errors. With this line of code in place, atleast non-navigational entities are working fine, but with this even that stops working.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/GestionPilotosEscuderia/GetPiloto",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(data){
     //you can use $.each to loop on the data.
     console.log(data)
  },
  error: function(error){
     alert(error);
  }
});
```